# how can I control my erros in controller codeigniter , and at the moment when I load the table it wont do it

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter-3

first at all I want to capture my erros using json. I have error, msg ,and duplicate. I want to check if whatever I am passing to my array is not empty, and If I have duplicate records it will go by duplicate `['duplicate'] ="some msg"`, and if not any of those then  `['msg'] ="ok"`, but how can I capture from model or controller the duplicate records from my array, and compare with. On the other hand on my ajax I'm tryining to load again my table for no refreshing my page every time. I want to see if the items were added.i was tryning this `//$('tbody').load(URL_GET_DATATABLE);`, but it doesn't work. How can I fix it?

controller

```
   public function addProduct(){
        $descripcion = $this->input->post('description');
        $cost_price =  $this->input->post('cost_price');
        $selling_price = $this->input->post('selling_price');
        $wprice = $this->input->post('wprice');
        $stock = $this->input->post('stock');
        $data = array(
            'descripcion' => $descripcion,
            'precio_compra' => $cost_price,
            'precio_venta' => $selling_price,
            'precio_mayoreo' => $wprice,
            'existencia' => $stock
        );
        $product = $this->products->addProduct($data);
        if (!empty($product)) {
            $this->json(array('error' => "it could'nt be added"));
        }else if (condition) {
            # code...
        }else{
            $this->json(array('msg' => 'successfully added'));
        }

    }
```

model

```
public function addProduct($data){
        $this->db->select('descripcion');
        $this->db->from('storelte_articulos');
        $this->db->where('descripcion',$data['descripcion']);
        $query = $this->db->get();
        if ($query->num_rows() > 0) {
            //echo 'repedito';// I need to use return 
            //return true;
        }else{
            //echo 'bien'; //I need to use return 
            //return false;
            $this->db->insert('storelte_articulos',$data);
        }
    }
```

ajax

```
  if($("#new_product").valid()){
                        $.ajax({
                            url: URL_GET_ADD_PRODUCT,
                            type: 'POST',
                            data: {description: description, cost_price: cost_price, selling_price: selling_price, wprice: wprice, stock: stock}
                        }).done(function (data) {
                            if (data.msg == 'successfully added') {
                                $('#new_product')[0].reset();
                                //$('tbody').load(URL_GET_DATATABLE);
                            }else{
                                alert(2)
                            }
                        });
                        return false;
                    }
```